Copy File From One Image to other
I want to Copy the file from one image and use it in another image
Dockerfile.build
ARG BASE_IMAGE

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json  lock_node_version.js ./

RUN npm install --save-dev typescript

RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

Dockerfile
ARG BASE_IMAGE

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} as base

COPY .env ./.env

COPY /usr/src/app/appspec.yml . # want to copy this file from the Dockerfile.build

EXPOSE 4000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start-prod"]


COPY /usr/src/app/appspec.yml .

I want to copy /usr/src/app/appspec.yml file from the Dockerfile.build to Dockerfile

Take a look at this post : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331645/extract-file-from-docker-image
